# remove links from all images in wordpress w/o touching functions.php

Tags: image, wordpress

I want to remove the links from all my images in my posts because I now have links in my captions. I know how to do it one by one but I have hundreds of images so that isn't an ideal option.

I know there is some code you can add to your functions.php page but my theme wont let me touch that file. If I do, it takes down the site.

Is there some other file I can edit? I looked at media.php, but wasn't sure what to do.

In case you need it, my site is [BitsyBride.com](http://BitsyBride.com).

Comment: So you want the images NOT to link anywhere. Why? And how is your theme is stopping you edit functions.php?

Comment: There's an error in your header, it's outputting `<script src="/home/content/24/7510724/html/wp-content/themes/basement/wp-content/themes/basement/js/jquery.wookmark.js"></script>` - path/dir mixed up with URL by the looks of it.

Comment: I don't want links when you click on the image. I want it set to None, like you can when you do it one by one in the image editor.

Comment: popnoodles, when I removed that script, I got the following error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/24/7510724/html/wp-content/themes/basement/functions.php:182) in /home/content/24/7510724/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881

Comment: nevermind. I uploaded the original header.php file without that script and it is fine now. That is unrelated to the original issue though.

Comment: I never said remove it. When you edit the files it messes them up. Something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

All your links and images are stored in the database, you can use an extension [such as this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/) one to do a mass search and replace from within the WordPress admin panel

Comment: i would avoid a permanent solution like this. working with display logic is a lot safer, and she can change it up later on if she does want those links back.

Answer (score 0):

another [hacky] approach is that you can use Javascript that loads on every page that finds all links containing images and removes the link, and retains the image.

Comment: i thought this too but it doesn't make sense not to do it in the theme.

Comment: agreed. something tells me the attempts to edit the functions.php file is being done in the actual WP theme editor, rather than using a real tool. also, the theme probably breaks as a result of bad code, and she probably isn't seeing an error.

Comment: when I edit the funtions.php through the wordpress editor, it just adds whatever code I add to the top of the webpage so it is visible to everyone. If I try to delete the code I added, it takes down the site.

Comment: Should I be editing the file in something like textpad instead?

Comment: typically, yes. You have more options in terms of editing. for one, you can use a file editor that has code help, and syntax highlighting (which will show you when your code has errors in it).